# How to use info with awk or gawk?

Tags: awk, info

Try to search index with `i` after `info awk`, it says no indices found. So i switch to `info gawk`, and execute `i gensub`, but it didn't jump to `gensub` function. Result of `I gensub` is:

```
Index entries that match 'gensub':

* Menu:

* '&' (ampersand), 'gsub()'/'gensub()'/'sub()' functions and: Gory Details. 
                                                              (line    6)
* '\' (backslash), 'gsub()'/'gensub()'/'sub()' functions and: Gory Details. 
                                                              (line    6)
* ampersand ('&'), 'gsub()'/'gensub()'/'sub()' functions and: Gory Details. 
                                                              (line    6)
* backslash ('\'), 'gsub()'/'gensub()'/'sub()' functions and: Gory Details. 
                                                              (line    6)
* escape processing, 'gsub()'/'gensub()'/'sub()' functions: Gory Details. 
                                                              (line    6)
* 'gensub':                              Using Constant Regexps. 
                                                              (line   43)
* 'gensub' <1>:                          String Functions.    (line   89)
* 'gensub()' function ('gawk'), escape processing: Gory Details. 
                                                              (line    6)
```

I get similar result when i search `FS`, `OFS`...

The gawk info comes from the `gawk-doc` package on unbuntu 16.04.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is a bug in the documentation. The section on Using [Constant Regexps (6.1.2.1)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Constant-Regexps) comes well before the section on [String Functions (9.1.3)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions), which contains the actual `gensub` documentation. Looking at [the source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/doc/gawktexi.in#n10886):

```
@cindexgawkfunc{gensub}
@cindexawkfunc{sub}
@cindexawkfunc{gsub}
Constant regular expressions are also used as the first argument for
the @code{gensub()}, @code{sub()}, and @code{gsub()} functions, as the
second argument of the @code{match()} function,
```

That's the first appearance of `@cindexgawkfunc{gensub}`, the second being the [actual function docs](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/doc/gawktexi.in#n17484). They should have used a different label for the first instance.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation, didn't expect someone would dig so deep. I know nothing about texinfo grammar, so i can't tell if you are right.  It seems to me that nearly all  indices are broken in someway. I guess i have to use man or html in this case.

Comment: @dedowsdi Yes, many are repeated. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Index Many indices aren't exactly duplicated, though (most have some qualifying clause like "gensub() function (gawk), escape processing").